# Converting UNet model outputs from logits to segmentation masks

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I've been recently working on segmentation task on certain CT scans. I decided to use `Python` as the language, `ResidualUNet` model architecture implemented in MONAI, evaluated by DiceLoss.
Everything went smoothly until the interference of a trained model. This ResidualUNet does **not have** a Softmax or Sigmoid layer, so it outputs raw logits, being floats ranging from around `-30` to `12`.
How could I properly convert those logits to obtain probabilites of each pixel belonging to each class?
The input, in notation of `BCHWD`, is `1x1x256x256x256`, being of course the image itself, while the output is `1x9x256x256x256`, each channel being a mask for different class.
The code for inference looks more less like this:

```
device = (
    "cuda"
    if torch.cuda.is_available()
    else "mps"
    if torch.backends.mps.is_available()
    else "cpu"
)

model = Unet(
    spatial_dims = 3,
    in_channels = 1,
    out_channels = 9,
    channels = (8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256),
    strides = (2,2,2,2,2),
    num_res_units = 4,
    norm = Norm.INSTANCE
).to(device)

model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH_TO_SAVED_MODEL_OBJECT)["model_state_dict"])

inputs, labels = next(iter(validation_dataloader))   # obtaining only one image - batch_size=1
inferer = SimpleInferer()   # simple inferer from monai.inferers
inputs = inputs.to(device)  # pass to GPU
labels = labels.to(device)  # pass to GPU
pred = inferer(inputs = inputs, network=model)
pred = pred.detach().cpu().numpy() # conversion to numpy array for viewing purposes
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a multiclass classification such that each pixel can belong to multiple classes, you can use sigmoid i.e., `prob = torch.sigmoid(pred)` which will give you the probability of each pixel belonging to each class independently, and if you need a single-class classification, you can use softmax i.e., `prob = torch.softmax(pred, dim=1)`. Both of these will convert the logits to valid probability distributions.

Comment: Thank you @Abhinav - I forgot to mention - yes, the task is a multi-class, multi-label segmentation. In the long run, I would like to make this a single-class classification. So, please correct me if I am wrong - using softmax will let me determine the maximum probability among the 9 output channels, but how can I determine which channel does that probability come from?

Comment: You can use `argmax` for that. It basically gives you the index at which value is maximum.